# Excel substitute for FIND Function when searching for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to find whether a given cell has a value that is included in a list.  Then I want to make the equation dynamic so that it results in a different output based on which item in the list it is.  There should be an equation in column B (Index/Match?) that returns a value from column D based on whether the value in column A contains one of the codes in Column C.

```
Column A     Column B              Column C    Column D
ABC12D       Equation=$40          ABC         $40
XYZ15Q       Equation=$20          MNO         $30
MNO26P       Equation=$30          XYZ         $20
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you include the desired output?

Comment: OR already results in #VALUE. OR is a logical function and will return TRUE or FALSE. You probably need MATCH to start with.

Comment: Please share more about what you are trying to do. Share some sample data and your desired results from the function you are needing help with.

Comment: do you want to return the value from column A where B1 is found, or do you want to return Column B where A1 is found

Comment: I'm ultimately planning on turning it into a Vlookup to pull in an amount for the corresponding match.  For example, there would be amounts that I would pull in based on whether that series of characters appears in the reference cell in column A.  Say if ABC is in cell A1, then $40 is returned.   if XYZ is in cell A1, then $30 is returned

Comment: please show your actual set up.  SUMIFS() would probably be the best solution.  FIND would need to be in MATCH and INDEX as an array. But we cannot help much by trying to solve part when there are better formulas to solve the whole.

Comment: I can't show my actual setup because the information is proprietary to my company but I'll do my best to replicate it

Comment: Please see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With you setup you would use INDEX/MATCH with your FIND as an array formuls:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND($C$1:$C$3,A1)),0))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I get it, it works with the sample data but that's just a coincidence.  I'll delete my previous comment.  Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

The or statement in the excel function tests a series of logical statements. What you want is something more along the lines of the following.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(IFERROR(FIND(B1,A$1:A$5),"ERROR")<>"ERROR",ROW(A$1:A$5),""))}
```

This function could be pasted in Column C, for each item in Column B you are testing.

This is an array function, and after you enter it in the cell, you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it work

This function will search for the text in B1 in the range A1:A5 and report what coulmns it finds the text in B1 seperated by a comma and a space. In your example case, it woudl return `1`. If abc was also present in the third entry in Column A, then it would retrun `1, 3`

Just as a breakdown,

1. `FIND(B1,A$1:A$5)` searches for the text in B1 in the range A1:A5. It returns an array with the location of the text, in your example, it would return `{1,#VALUE,#VALUE}`
2. Since if the `FIND` funcition cannot locate the specified text, it returns the `#VALUE` error. `IFERROR(____,"ERROR")` catches `#VALUE` and replaces it with "ERROR". It modifies your array to `{1,"ERROR","ERROR"}`
3. The if statement `IF(___,ROW(A$1:A$5),"")` will return the row of the array if the array value is not `"ERROR"`, otherwise it will return a blank space. This will modify your array to `{1,"",""}`.
4. The `TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,_____)` statement joins the array together, seperated by a comma and a space. The `TRUE` argument skips blank sections of the array.

If you want to return a custom value based on what row it occurs in, you can replace `ROW(A$1:A$5)` with the range that has the corresponding value.

Comment: Much appreciated, I will have to look at this later in more depth to understand how it works.  Thanks again!