# Excel: Is there a way to perform vlookup formula based off of criteria and to loop this formula until a valid value is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Based off of Name column in Tab 2, perform a vlookup in Tab 1, given two criteria are met: name value is equal and number column is >= 1. If both these criteria are met, return the corresponding date. If the number is <1, continue to repeat vlookup formula until valid number is found.

Is this type of logic possible via excel formula?

Thanks for your help

Tab 1:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqp8l.png

Tab 2:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjnOZ.png

Comment: You could try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335639/excel-substitute-for-find-function-when-searching-for-multiple-criteria

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at that. Thanks!